Search by Custom Field content OR post id via the WordPress Dashboard
This codes works fine for searching by custom field content, but could someone help me to modify it so I can search by post id instead of one of the three custom fields?  I will only ever search for one of the 4 possible options never multiple.
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search' );
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {
$post_type = 'properties';
$custom_fields = array("custom_field_one","custom_field_two","custom_field_three",);
if( ! is_admin() )
    return;
if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
    return;
$search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

$query->query_vars['s'] = '';

if ( $search_term != '' ) {
    $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
    foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
        array_push( $meta_query, array(
            'key' => $custom_field,
            'value' => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));
    }
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
};

}

I worked it out for myself - just add a second code snippet!
I got the following from How to search custom posts by ID in WordPress dashboard on Codexin
/**
 * Add search custom posts by their ID in WordPress dashboard
 *
 */
add_action( 'parse_request', 'cdxn_search_by_id' );
function cdxn_search_by_id( $wp ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( !is_admin() && 'edit.php' != $pagenow && 'students' !== $_GET['post_type']) {
        return;
    }
        
    // If it's not a search return
    if( !isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
        
    // Validate the numeric value
    $id = absint( substr( $wp->query_vars['s'], 0 ) );
    if( !$id ) {
        return; 
    }
        
    unset( $wp->query_vars['s'] );
    $wp->query_vars['p'] = $id;
}

